# Is there a crypto function that would take 1 second to run?

Tags: encryption

Short version of the question: what if we encrypt or decrypt by running SHA-256 one million times repeatedly, beginning with the initial "phrase" or "object", so that the operation can take 1 second, won't take prevent hacker's brute-force attempts?

---

Details:

If the system has an encrypt and decrypt system that would first SHA-256 "abcde" first, and then SHA-256 on that result, for 1 million times, to see if the result matches with the stored encrypted-one-million-time token, then the hacker can try the system beginning with "aaaa" but not practical to try it until "zzzz", even if the password is just 4 characters long (such as a password for the PC or Mac).

I think one way hackers try to hack into a computer or system is that they just try most popular passwords or just passwords starting with a to z, aa to zz, ..., aaaa to zzzz.

So then, if the crypto function is designed to take at least 1 second to finish, won't that stop that brute-force attempt?

Otherwise, the hacker can try 500,000 possibility per second, and it doesn't take much effort.  Some system actually stops for 1 second between attempt (such as Unix login prompt), but it doesn't stop it if it is not through some UI interface for that 1 second delay.

Comment: Seems you want a password hash, such as [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2). Iterating SHA-256 was done in the earlier [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), but that turns out to a a poor idea because that's the kind of function it's each to accelerate using dedicated hardware.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption! duplicate candidates [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/72961/18298). [2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24/18298), and [the canonical question for password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735) from our venerable site information security

Answer (score 4):

The are already many solutions for this. See for instance [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), [Lyra2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyra2), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt).

They allow you to tune the number of iterations so that it takes needed time on particular device (CPU, GPU) to compute a hash.